# Get HttpContent from HttpObject Netty - Java

Tags: java, netty, httpcontent

i'm working with Netty. I have a HttpObject and i need the content (HttpContent). A cast don't work. What can i do then?

Greetings
Daniel

Answer (score 4):

[HttpObject](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpObject.java) has a few subinterfaces.  Among them are [HttpMessage](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpMessage.java) and [HttpContent](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpContent.java).  In general the HttpMessage represents the headers and the HttpContent represents the data.  Depending on how your pipeline is configured you may get the following:

- [FullHttpMessage](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/FullHttpMessage.java) which implements HttpMessage and HttpContent interfaces.
- 1 HttpMessage followed by n-1 HttpContent followed by 1 [LastHttpContent](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/LastHttpContent.java).

There are a few [http examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http) provided by Netty to demonstrate how to handle an HttpObject.  The https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/upload example shows how to handle the second option described above.

Comment: adding the request/response encoder/decoder or the codecs to the pipeline allow you to handle httpMessages. e.g. 
@Override
protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        if (isClient) {
            pipeline.addLast("codec", new HttpClientCodec());
        } else {
        }   pipeline.addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec());
        pipeline.addLast("aggegator",
            new HttpObjectAggregator(512 * 1024));
}

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm using LittleProxy. There i become a HttpObject. But so i can't get from a HttpObject the content? I need a FullHTTPMessage?

Comment: I'm not sure what interfaces LittleProxy provides but it sounds like it is exposing Netty's types. Also I'm not sure how LittleProxy provides messages to your application or how it allows configuration of the pipeline. In Netty you can configure the pipeline to control how objects are delivered to your application code.  Ultimately the two bullet points I listed above are the two options so you can test with 1 response what approach LittleProxy is taking.  If you get back a FullHttpMessage then it is option 1, else it is option 2.

Comment: @Daniel84 Does this make sense?  Did this info help for your situation?

Comment: I don't know why but it don't work. I don't have FullHttpMessage only HttpObject. I think LittleProxy is buggy or so. Maybe you have a last idea?

Comment: Again I'm not sure if LittleProxy is wrapping Netty interfaces or exposing different interfaces but from a Netty perspective this answer will give you the 2 ways to receive HTTP objects. Like I said above if you are not being passed a [FullHttpMessage](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/FullHttpMessage.java) then you will receive 1 HttpMessage object followed by n-1 HttpContent objects followed by 1 LastHttpContent.  What does the class hierarchy for HttpObject look like in LittleProxy?

Comment: What do you mean with "n-1"? And which class hierarchy do you mean? It's using netty..

Comment: n = the number of chunks used to represent the content.  You said "I don't have FullHttpMessage only HttpObject". Do you mean to say that LittleProxy is not exposing this class to you and has its own class hierarchy around Netty's classes, or you have not configured LittleProxy to provide these messages to you?  You are going to have to explain exactly what you are receiving, how you are configuring your pipeline in order to get more help, and some code.  What URL are you requesting content from, what does your request look like, and what do you expect the content to look like?

Comment: Do you not understand how to configure the pipeline?  You may want to follow the Netty examples as I suggested to understand the core concepts I am describing.